# Pass URL parameter into Database query in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to pass URL parameter into the SQL query. I have a column called `"puppy_id"` and one of the values is `puppy1`.
I want to call this URL :- `localhost:3000/api/puppies/puppy1`
and it should execute the query in the database `SELECT * FROM puppytable WHERE puppy_id='puppy1'` and return the output.

I have no problem to connect to the database. But, it is showing that no data returned. I think, I am doing something wrong in executing the query.

My Code :-

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var db = require('../queries');

router.get('/api/puppies/:puppy_id', db.getPuppyStatus);

module.exports = router;
```

queries.js

```
module.exports = {
  getPuppyStatus: getPuppyStatus
};

function getPuppyStatus(req, res, next) {
  var puppyID = parseInt(req.params.puppy_id);
  db.any('select * from puppytable where puppy_id =$1', puppyID)
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          data: data,
          message: 'Retrieved puppies'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
    });
}
```

`queries.js` is in root of project directory.
It is calling from here in `index.js`

```
var db = require('../queries');
```

This is my output :-

```
{"status":"success","data":[],"message":"Retrieved puppies"}
```

To debug when I am doing `console.log(puppyID);` , it is giving me `NaN`

What should be the recommended way to do this ?

Comment: what is `family_id` shouldn't it be `puppy_id` ? and also I can not see your `../queries.js` file, make sure sanitize input

Comment: Try to remove the parseInt, because you're passing a string and you're trying to convert it into a number it's normal to return NaN.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where `req.params.family_id` is coming from, but it looks like it should be `req.params.puppy_id` - as below - otherwise it would be undefined, which would not match anything in your database.

```
function getPuppyStatus(req, res, next) {
  var puppyID = req.params.puppy_id; 
  //call puppy_id, not family_id
  //puppy_id is also a string being passed in, it can't be turned into an integer
  db.any('select * from puppytable where puppy_id =$1', puppyID)
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          data: data,
          message: 'Retrieved puppies'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check. Still no data is returning

Comment: To debug when I am doing console.log(puppyID); , it is giving me NaN

Comment: @codeclue Just noticed you were also calling `parseInt(req.params.puppy_id)`, but `puppy_id` is a string (puppy1). I updated my answer above.

Comment: It is now detecting the params. But, not executing the db query

Comment: @codeclue try wrapping the `$1` in quotes: `db.any("select * from puppytable where puppy_id = '$1'", puppyID)`

Answer (score 1):

You're converting to a `number` a `string` "puppy1". This is the reason you're getting `NaN`.

I don't know what's the type of the `id` in your column.
You've two options:

1. `id` as `number`, try to send a number instead of a string and you're code should be fine.
2. `id` as `string`, remove the parseInt.

   ```
   var puppyID = req.params.puppy_id;
   ```